# json package not compatible with jdk 1.4

Tags: java, json, jdk1.4

i use the package from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107. it compiles perfectly, but when i try to run my servlet, i get an 500 error, root cause is

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/json/JSONException (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:539)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:123)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:251)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:55)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:187)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader.findClass(StandardClassLoader.java:621)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader.loadClass(StandardClassLoader.java:958)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader.loadClass(StandardClassLoader.java:857)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader.loadClass(StandardClassLoader.java:941)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader.loadClass(StandardClassLoader.java:857)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1430)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1289)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:302)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1618)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:1930)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:278)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:903)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:668)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:643)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:480)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:995)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:643)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:641)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:480)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:995)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.invoke(StandardContext.java:2416)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:180)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:643)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorDispatcherValve.invoke(ErrorDispatcherValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:641)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:641)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:480)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:995)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:643)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:480)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:995)
at org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:223)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:601)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:392)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:619)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)
```

anyone knows how to solve this? thanks

Comment: update your JDK? Or, if it is not possible, downgrade the artifact.

Comment: Can't upgrade JDK.. What does downgrade artifact mean?

Comment: It means that you could use an older version of the lib that is not working. A version that is working under java 4. By the way, java 4 is very, very, old, though I understand that you are probably working with legacy code.

Comment: The problem is I can't find such a file, I've tried lots of jar s and none works

Answer (score 1):

From MANIFEST

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: Benjamin
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_05
```

the library is compiled with JDK 1.7, you can download the [source code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/archive/master.zip) and compile yourself with JDK 1.4.

From the official [README](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/README)

> The package compiles on Java 1.2 thru Java 1.4.

or upgrade your Java Runtime to JDK 1.7.

Comment: I'm new to Java and have never compiled this before, are there any instructions on how to compile this?

Comment: Download the source code, create an Eclipse project, set your runtime to Java 1.4, right click over the project in the package explorer, click on export and choose JAR file.